# Problema de diseño en página web, solapamiento

Tags: html, css

Buen día, esto debe ser un problema básico pero aún no logro dominarlo, resulta que hay una web que se muestra de esta manera:

[image: Como está]

Pero debería verse la parte de servicios y luego abajo, esos 2 recuadros, estaba viendo que podría usarse `overflow o position` pero no funciona.

La idea es que se vea de esta forma:

[image: Ideal]

Adjunto pedazos del código para entender de mejor forma:

este es el index.html (router.html) [alojado en este sitio de MEGA](https://mega.nz/#!5wwiBCoB!uYMaVWil5Dru6L7I4qidgN0XAJEeTw_GvNRUE5_Zd48) y también mostrado a continuación:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <!-- Basic Page Needs
    ================================================== -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" /><![endif]-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>TALENTO GEM</title>    

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="preload" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">
    <link rel="preload" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">
    <link rel="preload" href="css/style.css" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">
    <link rel="preload" href="css/responsive.css" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">
    <link rel="preload" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500,600,700,100,800,900,400,200,300" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">
    <link rel="preload" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playball" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">

    <link href="css/nuevostyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">

<!-- ESTA PARTE NO LO INTERPRETA BIEN-->
<style type="text/css">
.block2 {
    width: 100%;
background-color:#7596CB;}
.msg {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 14pt;
color:white;
text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
font-size: 500%;
height:2em;
}
.block1 {
background-color:#7596CB;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: right top;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: right top;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: right top;
    text-align:center;
  width:600px;
  margin-left:-600px;
}
</style>

  </head>

<body>
    <div id="app" v-cloak>
      <div id="tf-home">
          <div class="overlay">
              <div id="sticky-anchor"></div>


<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="
background: white;
height: 15vh;
">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">

<button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
aria-expanded="false" class="navbar-toggle collapsed ">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>

<a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand hidden-xs hidden-sm" style="padding: 0px 15px; margin-left:30%;"><img src="img/logo.jpg" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" style="height: 13vh;"></a>
<a class="navbar-header" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo-s.jpg" style="height:70px; weight:auto; margin-left:5%; margin-bottom:5%;" class="visible-xs visible-sm"/></a></div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <!-- que es esto -->

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="
margin-top: 0 !important;
color: black;
">
<li><a href="router.html" v-if="personaLogueada">Mi Perfil</a></li>
<li><a href="routerf6f2.html?page=blog" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning btn-circle"><span class="fa fa-rss hidden-xs"></span><span class="visible-xs">Blog</span></a></li>
<li><a target="new" href="mailto:gestion@graphicsexecutive.com" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning btn-circle"><span class="fa fa-envelope-o hidden-xs"></span><span class="visible-xs">Contacto</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
</header>

<div class="block0">
  <div class="col-sm-4">

    <div class="block1">
        <table class="block2">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="msg">SERVICIOS</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

   <div class="col-sm-8">col-sm-8 <br/>asdasd </div>

</div>


<!-- FIN ESTA PARTE NO LO INTERPRETA BIEN-->

<style>
.container{
  overflow: hidden!important;
  position: absolute!important;
}
</style>

              <div class="container">
                <form classi="form-inline">
                  <div class="content" style="color:#444 !important;padding-top:5% !important">

                    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 40px; padding-bottom: 80px">
                      <div class="col-sm-6">

                        <div class="box"> <!--- *** -->

                        <div class="row" style="padding-top: 40px; padding-bottom: 80px">
                          <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">


                            <h3><b>BUSCAS EMPLEO? <a class="btn3" href="#" @click="ingresar()" v-if="!personaLogueada" style="color: blue">Ingresar</a></b></h3>
                            <ul style="text-align:left">
                              <li><h5><b>Crea un CV de manera fácil, rápida y dinámica</b></h5></li>
                              <li><h5><b>Muestra lo que esperan ver de tí</b></h5></li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                                <div class="row" style="padding-top: 0px">
                          <div class="col-sm-3" >
                            <img src="img/Home_Ico1.png" height="90px">
                            <h4 style="color:black">1. Crea tu Usuario</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <img src="img/Home_Ico2.png" height="90px">
                            <h4 style="color:black">2. Completa e Ingresa los campos de CV</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <img src="img/Home_Ico3.png" height="90px">
                            <h4 style="color:black">3. Revisa tu CV y envía!</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <img src="img/Home_Ico4.png" height="90px">
                            <h4 style="color:black">4. En pocos minutos ya tienes TU CV y visible para todos</h4>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </div> <!-- *** -->


                      <div class="col-sm-6">

                        <div class="box1"> <!--- *** -->

                        <div class="row" style="padding-top: 40px; padding-bottom: 80px">
                          <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <h3><b>BUSCAS PERSONAS? <a href="#" @click="ingresar()" v-if="!personaLogueada" style="color: blue">Ingresar</a></b></h3>
                            <ul style="text-align:left">
                              <li><h5><b>Publica tu necesidad</b></h5></li>
                              <li><h5><b>Recibe y evalua candidatos!!!</b></h5></li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                                <div class="row" style="padding-top: 0px">
                          <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1" >
                            <img src="img/Home_Ico1.png" height="90px">
                            <h4 style="color:black">1. Crea tu Usuario</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <img src="img/Home_Ico2.png" height="90px">
                            <h4 style="color:black">2. Publica tu necesidad</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <img src="img/Home_Ico3.png" height="90px">
                            <h4 style="color:black">3. Recibe candidatos!!!</h4>
                          </div>
                        </div>  </div> <!--- *** --->
                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>

                </form>

              </div>

         </div>


      <div id="tf-service" class="hidden">
          <div class="container">

              <div class="col-md-4">

                  <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h4 class="media-heading">Encuentra un trabajo acorde a tus fortalezas.</h4>
                    <img src="img/i2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded"/>
                    <br/>
                    <p>Preséntate. Vidéate. Destaca!</p>
                    <h4>Talento es actitud </h4>
                    </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>

              </div>

              <div class="col-md-4">

                  <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h4 class="media-heading">¿Por qué un video?</h4>
                      <p>Es más rápido, personal y completo. Comunica mejor. </p>
                    <p>Va directo a la parte principal del proceso de reclutamiento: reconocerse.</p>
                    <p>En TALENTO GEM las personas que buscan empleo suben un video, destacando su experiencia y fortalezas personales. Las empresas que necesitan incorporar colaboradores, reclutan en base a criterios de trayectoria y habilidades clave. </p>

                    <img src="img/i1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded"/><br/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div id="tf-about" class="hidden">
          <div class="overlay">
              <div class="container">
                  <div class="row">

                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div id="tf-why-me" class="hidden">
          <div class="overlay">
          </div>
      </div>

      <nav id="tf-footer">

      </nav>


    <v-login ref="login" v-model="personaLogueada" @onlogin="loginOK"></v-login>
  </div>


<script type="text/x-template" id="login-template">
  <div id="divlogin" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header text-center">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h5><b>Bienvenid@ a TALENTO GEM</b></h5>
        </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

            <form >
              <!--<p>Por favor, ingresa tus credenciales... </p>-->
              <div class="content" style="padding:5px !important">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6 align-center">
                    <!--<label class="control-label" for="nombre">Mail</label>-->
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="mail" placeholder="Mail"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6 align-center">
                    <!--<label class="control-label" for="rut">Password</label>-->
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" v-model="password" placeholder="Password">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" v-model="password2" v-if="emailRegistrado==2" placeholder="Confirmar clave">
                  </div>

                </div>
                <hr/>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6 align-center">
                    <a class="form-control btn btn btn-primary" v-if="emailValido && emailRegistrado==1"  @click="login">Ingresar</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6 align-center">
                    <a class="form-control btn btn btn-primary" v-if="emailValido && emailRegistrado==1"  @click="enviarCredenciales">Enviarme credenciales por Mail</a>
                    <a class="form-control btn btn btn-primary" v-if="emailValido && emailRegistrado==2 && passwordCoinciden" @click="registrarCandidato">Registrarme como Candidato</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>   
            </form>
          </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>

  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
  <script src="js/vue/vue.min.js"></script><script src="js/vue/vue.menu.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script>
            var queryString = [];
            var contactoAnteErroresMail = 'contacto@talentogem.cl';
            var PERSONA_LOGUEADA = {
                PERS_ID: '',
                COPE_ID: '',
                PERF_ID: ''
            };
            var mensaje = '';

        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validaciones.js"></script>
        <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
        <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-123717870-1"></script>
        <script>
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag("js", new Date());

            gtag("config", "UA-123717870-1");
        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main8b19.js?v=1557269742"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/moment.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/vue/vue.login.js"></script>

  </body>

<!-- Mirrored from talentogem.cl/router.php by HTTrack Website Copier/3.x [XR&CO'2014], Thu, 18 Jul 2019 05:54:31 GMT -->
</html>
```

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, estoy seguro que es un problema muy básico, muchas gracias de antemano de cualquier comentario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en la seccion de tu container tienes mal escrito class:

```
<div class="container">
            <form classi="form-inline">
```

Para bajar tus recuadros, e me ocurre de la siguiente forma(Agregando un height):

```
<div class="col-sm-8" style="height:40em !important">col-sm-8 <br/>aqui agregue el height</div>
```

completo quedaria asi:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <!-- Basic Page Needs
    ================================================== -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" /><![endif]-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>TALENTO GEM</title>    

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="preload" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">
    <link rel="preload" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">
    <link rel="preload" href="css/style.css" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">
    <link rel="preload" href="css/responsive.css" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">
    <link rel="preload" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500,600,700,100,800,900,400,200,300" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">
    <link rel="preload" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playball" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">

    <link href="css/nuevostyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">

<!-- ESTA PARTE NO LO INTERPRETA BIEN-->
<style type="text/css">
.block2 {
    width: 100%;
background-color:#7596CB;}
.msg {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 14pt;
color:white;
text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
font-size: 500%;
height:2em;
}
.block1 {
background-color:#7596CB;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: right top;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: right top;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: right top;
    text-align:center;
  width:600px;
  margin-left:-600px;
}
</style>

  </head>

<body>
    <div id="app" v-cloak>
      <div id="tf-home">
          <div class="overlay">
              <div id="sticky-anchor"></div>


<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="
background: white;
height: 15vh;
">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">

<button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
aria-expanded="false" class="navbar-toggle collapsed ">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>

<a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand hidden-xs hidden-sm" style="padding: 0px 15px; margin-left:30%;"><img src="img/logo.jpg" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" style="height: 13vh;"></a>
<a class="navbar-header" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo-s.jpg" style="height:70px; weight:auto; margin-left:5%; margin-bottom:5%;" class="visible-xs visible-sm"/></a></div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <!-- que es esto -->

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="
margin-top: 0 !important;
color: black;
">
<li><a href="router.html" v-if="personaLogueada">Mi Perfil</a></li>
<li><a href="routerf6f2.html?page=blog" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning btn-circle"><span class="fa fa-rss hidden-xs"></span><span class="visible-xs">Blog</span></a></li>
<li><a target="new" href="mailto:gestion@graphicsexecutive.com" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning btn-circle"><span class="fa fa-envelope-o hidden-xs"></span><span class="visible-xs">Contacto</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
</header>

<div class="block0">
  <div class="col-sm-4">

    <div class="block1">
        <table class="block2">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="msg">SERVICIOS</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
   <div class="col-sm-8" style="height:40em !important">col-sm-8 <br/>aqui agregue el height </div>
</div>


<!-- FIN ESTA PARTE NO LO INTERPRETA BIEN-->

<style>
.container{
  overflow: hidden!important;
  position: absolute!important;
}
</style>

              <div class="container">
                <form class="form-inline">
                  <div class="content" style="color:#444 !important;padding-top:5% !important">

                    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 40px; padding-bottom: 80px">
                      <div class="col-sm-6">

                        <div class="box"> <!--- *** -->

                        <div class="row" style="padding-top: 40px; padding-bottom: 80px">
                          <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">


                            <h3><b>BUSCAS EMPLEO? <a class="btn3" href="#" @click="ingresar()" v-if="!personaLogueada" style="color: blue">Ingresar</a></b></h3>
                            <ul style="text-align:left">
                              <li><h5><b>Crea un CV de manera fácil, rápida y dinámica</b></h5></li>
                              <li><h5><b>Muestra lo que esperan ver de tí</b></h5></li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                                <div class="row" style="padding-top: 0px">
                          <div class="col-sm-3" >
                            <img src="img/Home_Ico1.png" height="90px">
                            <h4 style="color:black">1. Crea tu Usuario</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <img src="img/Home_Ico2.png" height="90px">
                            <h4 style="color:black">2. Completa e Ingresa los campos de CV</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <img src="img/Home_Ico3.png" height="90px">
                            <h4 style="color:black">3. Revisa tu CV y envía!</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <img src="img/Home_Ico4.png" height="90px">
                            <h4 style="color:black">4. En pocos minutos ya tienes TU CV y visible para todos</h4>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </div> <!-- *** -->


                      <div class="col-sm-6">

                        <div class="box1"> <!--- *** -->

                        <div class="row" style="padding-top: 40px; padding-bottom: 80px">
                          <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <h3><b>BUSCAS PERSONAS? <a href="#" @click="ingresar()" v-if="!personaLogueada" style="color: blue">Ingresar</a></b></h3>
                            <ul style="text-align:left">
                              <li><h5><b>Publica tu necesidad</b></h5></li>
                              <li><h5><b>Recibe y evalua candidatos!!!</b></h5></li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                                <div class="row" style="padding-top: 0px">
                          <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1" >
                            <img src="img/Home_Ico1.png" height="90px">
                            <h4 style="color:black">1. Crea tu Usuario</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <img src="img/Home_Ico2.png" height="90px">
                            <h4 style="color:black">2. Publica tu necesidad</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <img src="img/Home_Ico3.png" height="90px">
                            <h4 style="color:black">3. Recibe candidatos!!!</h4>
                          </div>
                        </div>  </div> <!--- *** --->
                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>

                </form>

              </div>

         </div>


      <div id="tf-service" class="hidden">
          <div class="container">

              <div class="col-md-4">

                  <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h4 class="media-heading">Encuentra un trabajo acorde a tus fortalezas.</h4>
                    <img src="img/i2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded"/>
                    <br/>
                    <p>Preséntate. Vidéate. Destaca!</p>
                    <h4>Talento es actitud </h4>
                    </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>

              </div>

              <div class="col-md-4">

                  <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h4 class="media-heading">¿Por qué un video?</h4>
                      <p>Es más rápido, personal y completo. Comunica mejor. </p>
                    <p>Va directo a la parte principal del proceso de reclutamiento: reconocerse.</p>
                    <p>En TALENTO GEM las personas que buscan empleo suben un video, destacando su experiencia y fortalezas personales. Las empresas que necesitan incorporar colaboradores, reclutan en base a criterios de trayectoria y habilidades clave. </p>

                    <img src="img/i1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded"/><br/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div id="tf-about" class="hidden">
          <div class="overlay">
              <div class="container">
                  <div class="row">

                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div id="tf-why-me" class="hidden">
          <div class="overlay">
          </div>
      </div>

      <nav id="tf-footer">

      </nav>


    <v-login ref="login" v-model="personaLogueada" @onlogin="loginOK"></v-login>
  </div>


<script type="text/x-template" id="login-template">
  <div id="divlogin" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header text-center">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h5><b>Bienvenid@ a TALENTO GEM</b></h5>
        </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

            <form >
              <!--<p>Por favor, ingresa tus credenciales... </p>-->
              <div class="content" style="padding:5px !important">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6 align-center">
                    <!--<label class="control-label" for="nombre">Mail</label>-->
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="mail" placeholder="Mail"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6 align-center">
                    <!--<label class="control-label" for="rut">Password</label>-->
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" v-model="password" placeholder="Password">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" v-model="password2" v-if="emailRegistrado==2" placeholder="Confirmar clave">
                  </div>

                </div>
                <hr/>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6 align-center">
                    <a class="form-control btn btn btn-primary" v-if="emailValido && emailRegistrado==1"  @click="login">Ingresar</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6 align-center">
                    <a class="form-control btn btn btn-primary" v-if="emailValido && emailRegistrado==1"  @click="enviarCredenciales">Enviarme credenciales por Mail</a>
                    <a class="form-control btn btn btn-primary" v-if="emailValido && emailRegistrado==2 && passwordCoinciden" @click="registrarCandidato">Registrarme como Candidato</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>   
            </form>
          </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>

  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
  <script src="js/vue/vue.min.js"></script><script src="js/vue/vue.menu.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script>
            var queryString = [];
            var contactoAnteErroresMail = 'contacto@talentogem.cl';
            var PERSONA_LOGUEADA = {
                PERS_ID: '',
                COPE_ID: '',
                PERF_ID: ''
            };
            var mensaje = '';

        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validaciones.js"></script>
        <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
        <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-123717870-1"></script>
        <script>
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag("js", new Date());

            gtag("config", "UA-123717870-1");
        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main8b19.js?v=1557269742"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/moment.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/vue/vue.login.js"></script>

  </body>

<!-- Mirrored from talentogem.cl/router.php by HTTrack Website Copier/3.x [XR&CO'2014], Thu, 18 Jul 2019 05:54:31 GMT -->
</html>
```

Espero te sirva de algo, Saludos.